# What's publishHtml reportFiles parameter syntax

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm trying to configure HTML Publisher plugin for Jenkins via Jenkinsfile to publish few html files like this:

```
    publishHTML(
        target: [
              allowMissing         : false,
              alwaysLinkToLastBuild: false,
              keepAll              : true,
              reportDir            : 'my-project-grails/build/reports/codenarc',
              reportFiles          : 'test.html',
              reportName           : "Codenarc Report"
        ]
    )
```

The description of the `reportFiles` parameter [here](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/htmlpublisher/) says I should be able to specify multiple files. But what's the syntax?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

"you can specify multiple comma-separated pages and each will be a tab on the report page" (from the [plugin docs](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/HTML+Publisher+Plugin)).

so i think it's:

```
reportFiles: 'test.html,other.html'
```

can it support wildcards like `*.html`? no, but there are some workarounds at https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-7139.

Answer (score 18):

If you have several HTML files but do not know their name nor count in advance, you can do such code:

```
script {
    def htmlFiles
    dir ('reports') {
        htmlFiles = findFiles glob: '*.html'
    }
    publishHTML([
            reportDir: 'reports',
            reportFiles: htmlFiles.join(','),
            reportName: 'Newman Collection Results',
            allowMissing: true,
            alwaysLinkToLastBuild: true,
            keepAll: true])
}
```

Notice the `script` section as Jenkins does not allow to declare variable in `stage` or `steps` section.

Comment: Just make sure to have the "Pipeline Utility Steps" plugin installed to get the `findFiles` function.

Comment: For reference `findFiles` has two parameter [`glob`](https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-utility-steps-plugin/blob/master/src/main/resources/org/jenkinsci/plugins/pipeline/utility/steps/fs/FindFilesStep/help-glob.html) and [`exclusions`](https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-utility-steps-plugin/blob/master/src/main/resources/org/jenkinsci/plugins/pipeline/utility/steps/fs/FindFilesStep/help-exclusions.html) bith of which supports an [_Ant style pattern_](https://ant.apache.org/manual/dirtasks.html#patterns) like `org/apache/**/CVS/*`.

Comment: be aware for findFiles to work  the plugin "Pipeline Utility Steps" needs to be installed i jenkins.

Comment: Fantasticly worked. upvoted

Answer (score 3):

As [Sebien's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49801311/12156188) but:

- Uses a one-liner for the files filter
- No need to be inside a `script` block
- Incorporates [Abhijit's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66271007/12156188)

```
publishHTML([
  reportName: 'Newman Report'
  reportDir: 'reports',
  reportFiles: "${dir('reports') { findFiles(glob: '**/*.html').join(',') ?: 'Not found' }}",
  allowMissing: true,
  alwaysLinkToLastBuild: true,
  keepAll: true,
])
```

Comment: i couldnt make it work like that,  https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-7139 suggest to put it inside a script{} and that one worked for me,   maybe because i didnt have the plugin "Pipeline Utility Steps"   did work after i got the plugin thanks for the idea, work great!

Answer (score 2):

You can specify multiple files and their locations.

```
publishHTML( [ 
                allowMissing: false, 
                alwaysLinkToLastBuild: false,
                keepAll: true, 
                reportDir: 'build/reports/', 
                reportFiles: 'TestResults.html, coverage/index.html', 
                reportTitles: 'Test Results, Coverage',
                reportName: 'Test Results Left side link'
] )
```

- **reportFiles**: First tab (Test Results) shows 1st reportFiles - TestResults.html while second tab (Coverage) shows 2nd reportFiles - coverage/index.html.
- **reportTitles**: Here reportTitles are name of the tabs.
- **reportName** is the link seen on job's page which links to the published html.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In Original Question there is syntax issue.
Missing "," after  --> reportFiles          : 'test.html'
This is causing DSL interpreter to expect another HTML file

Answer (score 0):

Sebien's answer using `findFiles` works, but it comes with a big gotcha. `findFiles` return an array, which if empty and joined, returns an empty string causing all files under the workspace to be published. To avoid this, do the following:

```
def htmlFiles = findFiles glob: '*.html'
htmlFiles = htmlFiles.join(",") ?: "Not Found"
```

and set `allowMissing: true`. There's also no need to define `htmlFiles` inside `dir ('reports')` closure.