# Jenkins htmlPublish function : All files are published including not html ones

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I would like to publish html files, it's possible that in my folder I end up with more then one file therefore I have defined the function as below :

```
dir("${WORKSPACE}/reports/${testScope}-${team}") {
      unstash "${testScope}-${team}-test-report"
      htmlFiles = findFiles glob: '*.html'
    }
    publishHTML(target: [
        allowMissing         : false,
        alwaysLinkToLastBuild: true,
        keepAll              : true,
        reportDir            : "${WORKSPACE}/reports/${testScope}-${team}/test/results/report/",
        reportFiles          :  htmlFiles.join(','),
        reportName           : "${testScope}-${team}",
        reportTitles         : "${testScope} ${team} Test report"
    ])
```

This is publishing all files in my folder even xml ones, is something wrong with my code?

Comment: Are you sure you installed the [utils as described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50675533/how-to-use-findfiles-in-a-jenkinsfile#50700189)? What did returned `htmlFiles` array look like (printed on console)? If empty, join will be empty and all files get published.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about adapting this answer:
[What's publishHtml reportFiles parameter syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44848582/whats-publishhtml-reportfiles-parameter-syntax)

```
publishHTML([
  reportName: 'Newman Report'
  reportDir: 'reports',
  reportFiles: "${dir('reports') { findFiles(glob: '**/*.html').join(',') ?: 'Not found' }}",
  allowMissing: true,
  alwaysLinkToLastBuild: true,
  keepAll: true,
])
```

The `dir()` *closure* is used directly inside the *G-string* as value assigned to parameter `reportFiles`.